# how to reference a relative file from code and tests

Tags: go, relative-path, revel

I need to reference `patients.json` from `patients.go`, here's the folder structure:

[image]

If I do:

`filepath.Abs("../../conf/patients.json")`

it works for `go test ./...` but fails for `revel run`

If I do:

`filepath.Abs("conf/patients.json")`

the exact opposite happens (revel is fine but tests fail).

Is there a way to correctly reference the file so that it works both for tests and normal program run?

Answer (score 11):

Relative paths are always interpreted / resolved to a base path: the *current* or *working* directory - therefore it will always have its limitations.

If you can live with always taking care of the proper working directory, you may keep using relative paths.

What I would suggest is to not rely on the working directory, but an explicitly specified base path. This may have a default value hard-coded in your application (which may be the working directory as well), and you should provide several ways to override its value.

Recommended ways to override the base path to which your "relative" paths are resolved against:

1. Command line flag (see [`flag`](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/) package)
2. Environment variable (see [`os.Getenv()`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv))
3. (Fix named) Config file in user's home directory (see [`os/user/User`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/user/#User) and [`os/user/Current()`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/user/#Current))

Once you have the base path, you can get the full path by joining the base path and the relative path. You may use [`path.Join()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/#Join) or [`filepath.Join()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Join), e.g.:

```
// Get base path, from any or from the combination of the above mentioned solutions
base := "/var/myapp"

// Relative path, resource to read/write from:
relf := "conf/patients.json"

// Full path that identifies the resource:
full := filepath.Join(base, relf) // full will be "/var/myapp/conf/patients.json"
```

Comment: is there a way to know the path of the `.go` file?

Comment: @PabloFernandez If it is compiled into an executable binary, there isn't even a `.go` file...

Comment: On Linux, if `/proc` is mounted, it's possible to know the location of the program being executed by calling [`os.Readlink()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Readlink) on the symlink named "/proc/self/exe".  In either case, it's a) not portable; b) may have little sense anyway as a properly packaged software package for a GNU/Linux-based system should have its binaries and "assets" separated anyway.

Comment: I'd mention another possibility as well: 1) have a global variable defining the base directory prefix for the assets, say, `main.AssetsDir`; 2) allow downstream packagers override it at build time using the linker's ability to override string-typed values, like with: `go build -ldflags="-X main.AssetsDir=/usr/share/cool_app/assets"`.  The OP could get more background on this by studying the outputs of `go help build` and `go tool link -h`.

Comment: @kostix Good idea, but that limits the configurability to developers. Users without programming knowledge would find command line flags much friendlier and easier to use than build flags.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used Revel myself but the following looks helpful to me:

http://revel.github.io/docs/godoc/revel.html

- `revel.BasePath`
- `revel.AppPath`

Comment: Not sure why but both `BasePath` and `AppPath` return the empty string :/

Comment: @PabloFernandez did you revel.Init()?

Comment: The link is dead. The new one seems to be [https://revel.github.io/](https://revel.github.io/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the problem with path, but the problem with your design.

You should design your code more careful.

As far as I can tell, you share same path in your test file and reveal run. I guess that maybe you hard code your `json` path in your model package which is not suggested.

Better way is

- model package get json path from global config, or init model with json path like `model := NewModel(config_path)`. so reveal run can init model with any json you want.
- hard code "`../../conf/patients.json`" in your xxxx_testing.go