# Relative paths in revel framework

Tags: go, revel

How can import a file realtive to the revel basefolder in revel framework. Currently I do the following to get hold of some config values.

```
file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("conf/config.conf")
...
```

This results in my server only working if i stand in the app directory when starting revel with

```
revel run myapp
```

Is there a way to access the base folder?

Comment: I found the revel.BasePath variable but it seems like its empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are exported global variables in the [`revel`](http://revel.github.io/docs/godoc/revel.html) package, you can use any of these:

```
var (
    // App details
    AppName    string // e.g. "sample"
    BasePath   string // e.g. "/Users/revel/gocode/src/corp/sample"
    AppPath    string // e.g. "/Users/revel/gocode/src/corp/sample/app"
    ViewsPath  string // e.g. "/Users/revel/gocode/src/corp/sample/app/views"
    ImportPath string // e.g. "corp/sample"
    SourcePath string // e.g. "/Users/revel/gocode/src"

    // Revel installation details
    RevelPath string // e.g. "/Users/revel/gocode/src/revel"

    // Where to look for templates and configuration.
    // Ordered by priority.  (Earlier paths take precedence over later paths.)
    CodePaths     []string
    ConfPaths     []string
    TemplatePaths []string
)
```

If it is empty for you, that is most likely because you started your app from the base folder.

Note that these paths are set by the [`Init(mode, importPath, srcPath string)`](http://revel.github.io/docs/godoc/revel.html#Init) function. It's documentation states:

> ```
> srcPath - the path to the source directory, containing Revel and the app.
>   If not specified (""), then a functioning Go installation is required.
> ```

Also check out: [how to reference a relative file from code and tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059023/how-to-reference-a-relative-file-from-code-and-tests)

Answer (score 1):

I use this method:
In conf/app.conf add a line with the configuration path of this way:

projectname.path = "/foldersnames/"

and in the controller Write a method like this:

```
func info(field string) string {                                                                                                                                                                               
  config, err := revel.LoadConfig("app.conf")                                                                                                                                                                  
  if err != nil || config == nil {                                                                                                                                                                             
    log.Fatalln("Failed to load configuration file", err)                                                                                                                                                      
   }                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  return config.StringDefault(field, "empty")                                                                                                                                                                  
}
```

You can build a helper with this code and take configurations variables from all applications.

You must call of this way:

```
info("projectname.path")
```