# File path in golang

Tags: go

I have a project with next structure:

```
|_main.go
|_config
  |_config.go
  |_config_test.go
  |_config.json
```

I'm having next code line in `config.go`:

```
file, _ := os.Open("config/config.json")
```

When I'm executing method contained this code line from `main.go` all is working. But when I'm trying to execute this method from `config_test.go` it produces error:

```
open config/config.json: no such file or directory
```

As I understood it is a working directory issue because I'm launching same code with relative path from different directories. How can I fix this problem without using full path in `config.go`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to reference a relative file from code and tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059023/how-to-reference-a-relative-file-from-code-and-tests)

Comment: You should not rely on the fact that the final compiled executable will be at the same location as its source code. There are several ways to specify which configuration file to use at runtime, the most obvious one being to pass it as a command line option. In this specific case, the path to the config file should be known by main.go and config_test.go, and vary accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relative paths are always resolved basis your current directory. Hence it's better to avoid relative paths.

Use command line [flags](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) or a configuration management tool (better approach) like [Viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper)

Also according to [The Twelve-Factor App](http://12factor.net/config) your config files should be outside your project.

**Eg usage with Viper:**

```
import "github.com/spf13/viper"

func init() {

    viper.SetConfigName("config")

    // Config files are stored here; multiple locations can be added
    viper.AddConfigPath("$HOME/configs")
    errViper := viper.ReadInConfig()

    if errViper != nil {
        panic(errViper)
    }
    // Get values from config.json
    val := viper.GetString("some_key")

    // Use the value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `os.Getwd()` to get "the current directory", i.e. the directory where main is called

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path"
)

func main() {
    projectDir, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        // handle error ...
        panic(err)
    }
    file_path := path.Join(projectDir, "config/config.json")
    fmt.Printf("config file path = %s", file_path)
}
```

Credit : https://gist.github.com/arxdsilva/4f73d6b89c9eac93d4ac887521121120