# Go template "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: go, go-templates

I have a weird problem with Go html template package. I'm getting template parsing error (system can't find the path specified) but it seems that path is ok relative to main.go file (template/base.html).

You can see my project folder structure on this screenshot, and also error that I'm talking about.

http://image.prntscr.com/image/42e8e8a6a31c4fe8af11cdc05890636f.png

Comment: File names are relative to the current working directory, not the .go file where the filename is used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to reference a relative file from code and tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059023/how-to-reference-a-relative-file-from-code-and-tests/31059125#31059125); and [How to Specify Path of Template for App Engine with Go for Unit Testing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320920/how-to-specify-path-of-template-for-app-engine-with-go-for-unit-testing/38322844#38322844)