# go test load files from root directory?

Tags: go

It seems `go test ./...` runs each test file using the file's directory as the root dir.

E.g., if a test is `my_project/service/service_test.go`, then it is run with root dir set to `my_project/service/`.

This causes trouble because I need to load config files during the test, which are located at `my_project/config`.

What I am doing now is setting an env variable `WORK_DIR`, setting it to `my_project`, and using it to load the config files.

Is there a feature in Go that allows setting the work dir for tests?

Comment: Please note I am not writing unit tests, but acceptance tests, which are for testing the service after it as been deployed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Specify Path of Template for App Engine with Go for Unit Testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320920/how-to-specify-path-of-template-for-app-engine-with-go-for-unit-testing/38322844#38322844); and [how to reference a relative file from code and tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059023/how-to-reference-a-relative-file-from-code-and-tests/31059125#31059125).

Comment: How do you test a service with `go test` after it has been deployed? That doesn't make sense to me. Don't you deploy the compiled binary?

Comment: I closed this as duplicate