# How to reliably refer to static file in a Go application?

Tags: go, static-files

I am writing a Go command-line tool that generates some files based on templates.

The templates are located in the Git repository alongside the code for the command-line tool itself.

I wanted to allow the following:

1. The binary, wherever it is called from, should always find the templates directory.
2. The templates directory can be overriden by the user if need be.

Since this is a Go application, I went with something like:

```
templateRoot := filepath.Join(
    os.Getenv("GOPATH"),
    "src/github.com/myuser/myproject/templates",
)
```

But being rather new to Go, I wonder if this approach is **reliable** enough: is it guaranteed that my application template will always be accessible at that path ?

What if someone vendorize my application into their own project ? Does that even make sense for a command-line tool ?

Because of 2., I obviously can't/won't use [go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata) because I want to allow for the templates to be overriden if need be.

In summary: what is a good strategy to reliably refer to non-go, static files in a Go command-line tool ?

Comment: You can't use GOPATH, because GOPATH is only used for building the application. You install the files into one or more well-known locations, like any other program would.

Comment: Well, this one is not overridable.

Comment: @JimB: Am I wrong to assume that `go get <myproject>` will "install" my command-line tool then ? I thought it was pretty idiomatic for Go tool to rely on the fact they were installed via `go get`.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [how to reference a relative file from code and tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059023/how-to-reference-a-relative-file-from-code-and-tests/31059125#31059125).

Comment: @ereOn: `go get` is a convenience for developers to fetch and build a go package. It relies on having a GOPATH (though there's a default now in go1.8), and GOBIN in your PATH. Many programs require extra steps not covered by the simple `go` tool, and have scripts or Makefiles to do the build. If you're targeting users that aren't developers, you ned to provide a way to install into standard system paths. Just provide a list of locations your program looks for templates.

Comment: @JimB That makes sense indeed. Thanks. BTW: I would accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GOPATH` is used for building the application. While you could look for `GOPATH` and check relative locations to each `GOPATH` entry at runtime, you can't be sure it will exist (unless of course you make it a prerequisite for running your application).

`go get` itself is a convenience for developers to fetch and build a go package. It relies on having a `GOPATH` (though there's a default now in go1.8), and `GOBIN` in your `PATH`. Many programs require extra steps not covered by the simple `go` tool, and have scripts or Makefiles to do the build. If you're targeting users that aren't developers, you need to provide a way to install into standard system paths anyway.

Do what any regular program would do, and use some well-known path to locate the template files. You can certainly add some logic in your program to check for a hierarchy of locations: relative to `$GOPATH`, relative to the binary, working directory, `$HOME`, etc; just provide a list of locations to the user that your program will look for templates.