# Golang Config File should load their own package

Tags: go

I have two projects those are
1. Web Project
2. Broker Project

```
services
    -web/util.go
    -main.go
    -cofig.json


broker
    -consumer/redis.go
    -consumer/mongo.go
    -main.go
    -<cofig.go>   //I do not want to make a copy here
```

I have developed an utility program for my web project which uses config.json file. In that utility program I use the code like

```
file, _ := os.Open("./config.json")
```

That is working fine.
When I included this project into Broker project like

```
package "services/web"
```

And I tried to utilize utility code in it but it tries to find 'config.json' from Broker project instead of "services web project". Due to this reason I need to copy the same file inside the Broker project.

Please help me to keep single file inside 'services/web'

Thanks is advance.

Regards,
Dinesh

Comment: are you sure relative file paths are correct?

Comment: That is not a case of relative or absolute path. I want to reuse existing code & doesn't want to duplicate. That's happening in current scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You need to approach the problem differently. You are compiling your code to a single binary file, so by the time your program is actually running, it has lost all of its package structure.

The simplest solution is to modify `services/web` to accept a `web.Config` struct instead of loading from a file. Then the consumer (the `broker` package in this case) is responsible for providing the config. It can use a file if it wants to.

Comment: @chawey I understood what you said. Now my concern is that when we build/install application for production then we need to change the path every time between window & Linux.
Please guide me how to configure path to that work on both envionments

Comment: Actually a good reference is the linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059023/how-to-reference-a-relative-file-from-code-and-tests.

Comment: @chawey Thanks. I understand the Golang.  How Golang works.