# How can i parse reactjs files in html/template panic: html/template: template.Must(template.ParseGlob("PersonalDetails.js"))

Tags: javascript, reactjs, go

for parsing reactjs file PersonalDetails.js

template.Must(template.ParseGlob("PersonalDetails.js"))

but its showing

panic: html/template: pattern matches no files: `PersonalDetails.js`

Comment: Make sure `PersonalDetails.js` is in the working directory, or also provide its path. Also to parse a template file (or multiple files) given by their names, use `template.ParseFiles()`.

Comment: is it possible to integrate go with reactjs as frontend and mysql as its database

Comment: Yes it is, why wouldn't it be?

Comment: i cant do it ....can u help me  out privately

Comment: func init() {
 db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root:root@/hrms")
 tpl, err = template.ParseFiles("src/app/index.js")
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
 }
 //tpl = template.New("").ParseFiles("src/*")
}

Comment: my folder structure is src/app in that app folder i have different subfolders which contain js files. subfolders like src/app/home/index.js , src/app/Admin/AdminUsers.js

I have created another folder src/app/go/personalDetails.go which contain the go files

so how to access the js files through go.

Comment: If yo want to parse files given by a glob such as `src/*`, you have to use `ParseGlob()`, you can't use `ParseFiles()` then, only if you explicitly list the file names.

Comment: when i use parseglob  it shows the following error Error loading templates:html/template: pattern matches no files: `src/app/*.js`

Comment: Then my very first comment applies again.

Comment: can u be more specific i cant get what u have said

Comment: The error means the pattern matches no files. This is because the path is relative, and it is resolved to the working directory. Either your working directory is not what you think, or that relative path is wrong.

Comment: My project directory is Project/src/app/.....in the app folder there are different subfolders like src/app/admin/AdminUsers.js or src/app/Employee/AddEmployee.js........and my go file is in src/app/go/details.go

Comment: The working directory is the folder from which you launch your app. So `src/app/*.js` must exist compared to that folder. Or use absolute path.

Comment: Please see related question: [how to reference a relative file from code and tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059023/how-to-reference-a-relative-file-from-code-and-tests/31059125#31059125)

Comment: i have around 100 js files to be parsed