# How to read a file present in a package into another file belonging to the same package?

Tags: go

I'm trying to a read a file (a.go) present in a package into another file (b.go) which is also present in the same package. I used **os.Open()** method but it is working only when i give the complete system path of the file(ex: home/bin/xyz/a.go).

But, I want the file (a.go) to be read into (b.go) *without using the entire system path*. Can anyone please help?

Folder

```
  -- a.go

  -- b.go
```

//Inside b.go we have a function//

```
func (xyz){

x:= os.Open("--path to a.go--") // This path shouldn't be the system path

}
```

Comment: Relative paths are always resolved to the working directory. Make sure you provide a relative path based on that. See [how to reference a relative file from code and tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059023/how-to-reference-a-relative-file-from-code-and-tests/31059125#31059125).

Comment: "But, I want the file (a.go) to be read into (b.go) without using the entire system path." You cannot do this. The running program does not know about your source code.

Comment: What makes you think that `a.go` will even be available where the program is executed?

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you actually trying to _accomplish_? Explain your goal, and we can help you solve that, rather than this wild goose chase for something you probably shouldn't do.

Answer (score -4):

You can get the path of the current file by using this technique.

```
_, srcpath, _, _ := runtime.Caller(0)
dirpath := filepath.Dir(srcpath)
err, fp := os.Open(filepath.Join(dirpath, "a.go"))
if err != nil {
     // err
}
...
fp.Close()
```